# How to check status for jobs in list each n seconds till all jobs finished?

Tags: python, while-loop, boto3, amazon-transcribe

I'm having a problem with checking the status for all my Transcription job before start another step. I need to know when all jobs in `myList` are `COMPLTETED` or `FAILED`, if it is false retry again 5 seconds later, but currently it keeps forever running, there is my python script:

```
while True:
    final_list = []
    for job in myList:
        status = transcribe.get_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job)
        final_list.append(status.get('TranscriptionJob').get('TranscriptionJobStatus'))

    if all(status in final_list for status in ['COMPLETED', 'FAILED']):
        break
    time.sleep(5)
```

**Edit 1**
Possible response status can be `QUEUED`, `IN_PROGRESS`, `FAILED`, `COMPLETED`

**Edit 2**
Omar was right I'm not extracting corretly the status of each job response but script still running forever.

Comment: What is example content of `final_list`?

Comment: @Marcin it can be: 'QUEUED' ,'IN_PROGRESS','FAILED' or 'COMPLETED'

Comment: Please update the question with the new data. Alsoyour `final_list` is not a valid python code anyway,

Comment: I have just updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response syntax of *get_transcription_job* method is:

```
{
    'TranscriptionJob': {
        'TranscriptionJobName': 'string',
        'TranscriptionJobStatus': 'QUEUED'|'IN_PROGRESS'|'FAILED'|'COMPLETED',
        ...
    }
}
```

So instead of adding 'status' object which contains other fields, you need to append status.get('TranscriptionJob').get('TranscriptionJobStatus')

Change:

```
final_list.append(status)
```

By:

```
final_list.append(status.get('TranscriptionJob').get('TranscriptionJobStatus'))
```

UPDATE:

According to what are you trying to do, the condition should be:

```
if all(status in ['COMPLETED', 'FAILED'] for status in final_list):
```

Because you need to validate that allowed values list ('COMPLETED', 'FAILED') contains all the elements of 'final_list'.

---

Reference:

[Boto3 get_transcription_job](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/transcribe.html#TranscribeService.Client.get_transcription_job)